# Display Folder in carousel

Tags: c#, image, uwp, directory, carousel

When createBtn button is clicked, it will display a custom dialog that contains a textbox for the user to type the name of the desired folder and after the user clicks okBtn, it will create a new folder with that name will be displayed on the carousel. But I encountered a problem that it can not display the folder on the carousel. (Folder has been successfully created on a local package "koleksibuku")

Code:

```
StorageFolder koleksibuku = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync("koleksibuku", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFolder namafolder = await koleksibuku.CreateFolderAsync(namaFolderBox.Text);
folder = await koleksibuku.GetFoldersAsync();
```

XAML:

```
 <layout:SfCarousel x:Name="carousel" Offset="150" SelectedItemOffset="60" SelectionChanged="carousel_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                    <layout:SfCarousel.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="grid4"  Background="{x:Null}" >
                                <Grid Background="White"  PointerPressed="UIElement_OnPointerPressed">
                                    <Image x:Name="cover" Width="300" Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="judulbuku"  Margin="10" Width="300"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                           FontSize="20"
                                                           Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                           TextAlignment="Center"
                                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" FontWeight="Bold" />

                                    <!--<Image x:Name="folder" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Source="ms-appx:///images/folders_png8761.png" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="judulfolder"  Margin="10" Width="300"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                           FontSize="20"
                                                           Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                           TextAlignment="Center"
                                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" FontWeight="Bold" />-->
                                </Grid>
                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Height="186" 
                                                       Margin="0 0 0 -180" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#41FFFFFF"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#19FFFFFF" Offset="0.259"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.681"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </layout:SfCarousel.ItemTemplate>
                </layout:SfCarousel>
```

How to handle it?

Note:
If folder, it will use the image of:ms-appx:///images/folders_png8761.png
whereas, if the file will render on the pdf file.

Comment: From which library is that carousel control? Does it support ItemsSource binding?

Comment: Carousel support ItemSource binding and is used to display files and folders in the folder "koleksibuku". The problem is the carousel can display the file, but can not display the folder. How to handle it?

Comment: Where's `SfCarousel` come from?

Comment: from syncfusion carousel

Comment: @Rose [syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/) is a third party *paid* package, we cannot help you. Please try to get support from the syncfusion team.